# How to search list items by regex with Aerospike Expressions

Tags: go, aerospike

We are migrating from our old aerospike version *3.15.1.4* to version *6.2.0.7*. This involves the migration from *aerospike-client-go v4.5.2+incompatible* to *aerospike-client-go/v6 v6.6.0*. Predicate Expressions (PredExp) have been deprecated since Aerospike Database 5.2. They were removed in Aerospike Database 6.0. So we have to move to Aerospike Expressions.

We have a bin with a string-list in it. And we want to do a search with a "begins-with" pattern. In the old world, we do that with following code:

```
as.NewPredExpStringVar("v"),
as.NewPredExpStringValue("^"+regexp.QuoteMeta("search_term")),
as.NewPredExpStringRegex(QueryRegexOptionExtended|QueryRegexOptionIgnoreCase),
as.NewPredExpListBin("ListField"),
as.NewPredExpListIterateOr("v"),
```

Following examples will search vor exact value in the "new world":

```
// As filter inside statement
as.NewContainsFilter("ListField", as.ICT_LIST, "search_term")

// As FilterExpression on query-policy
*as.ExpGreater(
    as.ExpListGetByValue(
        as.ListReturnTypeCount,
        as.ExpStringVal("search_term"),
        as.ExpListBin("ListField")),
    as.ExpIntVal(0),
```

**But how can we achive a "begins-with-search" with the new Aerospike Expressions?**

We tried the following, without success:

```
*as.ExpRegexCompare(
    "^"+regexp.QuoteMeta("search_term"),
    as.ExpRegexFlagICASE,
    as.ExpListBin("ListField"),
)
```

In the aerospike-logs, the following warning appears:

```
WARNING (exp): (exp.c:1469) build_cmp_regex - error 4 invalid arg type 4 (list) != 3 (str)
WARNING (query): (query.c:1485) basic query job failed msg field processing
```

---

For more background-info, this is the db-setup:

We have following model which is getting stored inside aerospike:

```
type MyModel struct {
    ListField []string
    [some-other-fields]
}
```

And following secondary index:
Index name: idx_MYSET_ListField / namespace: myns / set: MYSET / bin: ListField / bin: string / index: list / State: RW

And if I read a sample record over aql:

```
aql> select PK,ListField from myns.MYSET where PK = 12345
+--------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
| PK | ListField |
+--------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 12345 | LIST('["myid:1234", "testid2", "some-other-value", "more-values"]') |
+--------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Is your list of known fixed size? e.g. ["a", "b","c","d","e"] ...always exact 5 elements?

Comment: hi @pgupta: No, the list can contain 0:n elements. But what difference would a fixed size make?

Comment: just thinking what we could do in lieu of iteration...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expressions do not support iteration over lists or maps. The list and map APIs normally provide functionality that would solve the use-cases using the iteration provided by the old predexp. This is the first use-case I've come across that used iteration in a way that cannot be replicated with the list/map APIs.

As of 6.3, the only way to replicate this behavior may be to use a [Stream UDF](https://docs.aerospike.com/server/guide/stream_udf).

Comment: I suspected that this is no longer supported, since I couldn't find anything in the documentation. Thank you for the hint to Stream UDF. Sounds intresting and we will have a look at it.